# Create interval by string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time

Is it possible to create an interval by string in PostgreSQL?

for example, I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
 id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 data JSONB
);
INSERT INTO x(data) VALUES('{"day_sess":"4_1"}');

-- the query:
SELECT DISTINCT (INTERVAL (LEFT(data->>'day_sess',1) || ' days')) FROM x ORDER BY 1;
```

it always give

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah nevermind, found the answer

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(data->>'day_sess',1)::INT * (INTERVAL '1 day') 
FROM x ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: this is possibly the cleanest way, or you can do the concatenation as above and cast the result with `::interval`